# Can I watch what accesses a particular address?

Tags: ida, ollydbg

With Cheat Engine it is possible to watch a particular address and keep track of what has accessed a particular memory address. I was wondering if this can be done too with OllyDbg or IDA. I could not find anything that would do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use hardware log breakpoint for that purpose.

Go to the address you want to monitor in the dump window (e.g here, I want to monitor 0xCB7008):

[image]

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> on the chosen address in the dump window (or right click and `breakpoint > hardware log):

[image]

- Set `Break on` to `Access R/W`
- In `Expressions` enter once again the address in square brackets
- Set `Pause Program` to `never` if you don't want to stop on each access.
- Set `Log values of expressions` to `Always`

Note that the `data size` if not really important (1 byte will break for 2 or 4 bytes access).

Go to the log window (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>), press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to clear it, and run your program (<kbd>F9</kbd>).

In the log window: you should see all accesses to the memory (the leftmost column indicates the code address where the read/write happens):

[image]